# url marker in google map api using ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: google-maps, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Map in my page and when the marker is clicked it goes to a action Ballon in the RptVendedorController that is like this,

```
public ActionResult Balloon( int id,string tipoPin , bool clienteCompleto)
```

for the url of the marker I create like this

```
Url.Action("Balloon", "RptVendedor", new { id = cliente.ClienteId, tipoPin = "clientes", clienteCompleto = true }) }
```

that give this in server side

> url:/RptVendedor/Balloon/4?tipoPin=clientes&clienteCompleto=True

My problem is that for some reason  the url change and when I click the marker this is the url that i get (is below) it add (amp;) so it not hit my action because it not have well format the clientecompleto in the Query string

```
Request URL:http://localhost:10657/RptVendedor/Balloon/4?tipoPin=clientes&amp;clienteCompleto=True
```

and dont know the reason why it add the (amp;)?

Edit

i put to a viewModel

```
Globo = new MostrarMapaGlobo { Ancho = 400, Alto = 200, Url = Url.Action("Balloon", "RptVendedor", new { id = cliente.ClienteId, tipoPin = "clienteGeografico" }) }
```

and in a partial view

```
@foreach (var pin in Model.Pines)
        {
            <text>
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(@pin.Posicion.Latitud, @pin.Posicion.Longitud),
                map: map,
                title: '@pin.AltText',
                icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage('@Html.Raw(pin.Icono.Replace("[color]", pin.Color.Substring(1)))'),
                @if (pin.Click)
                {
                    @:clickable: true,
                }
                else
                {
                    @:clickable: false,
                }
                @if(pin.Movil)
                {
                    @:draggable: true,
                }
                else
                {
                    @:draggable: false,
                }

                @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pin.Globo.Extras))
                {
                    @pin.Globo.Extras@:,
                }
                ancho: '@pin.Globo.Ancho' + 'px',
                alto: '@pin.Globo.Alto' + 'px',
                url: '@pin.Globo.Url',
                contenido: '@pin.Globo.Contenido'
            });
            oms.addMarker(marker);
            markers.push(marker);
            </text>
                if (Model.Ruta != null && pin.Ruta)
                {
                @:posiciones.push(new google.maps.LatLng(@pin.Posicion.Latitud, @pin.Posicion.Longitud));                            
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where are you using the `Url.Action(...)`? In an hyperlink or in some script?

Comment: I edit the question i create in a viewmodel then in a viewmodel i put the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here you should unescape with `Html.Raw` :

```
...
url: '@Html.Raw(pin.Globo.Url)',
...
```